# Anonymous auth in an ACL on OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I am new-ish to LDAP, and I am studying now the ACLs ( OlcAccess )

So, on the OpenLDAP Official documentation, I found this example:

**access to attrs=userPassword
        by self =xw
        by anonymous auth
        by * none**

I was wondering what effect the line "by anonymous auth" has. I really can't grasp an anonymous user trying to authenticate, because if so, they wouldn't be anonymous any more, I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question was cross-posted on Stack Overflow, and I answered it there.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61521692